# Output Value of a neural network

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network

While working with the neural network toolbox in matlab.

After creating the network when I try to use it to classify between two classes I get some sort of similarity value.

The output of `sim(net,featureVector)` returns a matrix `Out` which is `[2x1]` each row with some value between `[0, 1]`

I know that sigmoid function returns a value between `[0, 1]` but the problem is like:

**if a sample is `n%` similar to class A then should'nt it be `(100-n)%` similar to class B.** ?

This is the output I got from few samples =>[where `HIT` and `FAIL` are two classes.]

[image: image1]

---

[image: image2]

So from the 2nd image it seems that the neural network returns some sort of similarity value independently of the two classes that surely does not follow above mentioned Rule.

It looks like it uses some minimum distance formula for each class and returns the results independently.

My exact question is.

**1. What exactly does `sim(net,featureVector)` method returns?**
 **2. Am I thinking right?**
 **3. If yes what minimum distance Algo it uses.**
 **4. Do point me to some links from where I can learn more.**

Comment: when you are performing classification using a machine learning algorithm. The prediction of a element to be in a class is independent of the other.Like in a 2 label classification. The probablity of an object to be in class 'A' is 'n'% then,  its probablity to be in class 'A' is not not 100-'n' % . It may be some other value. And sum of probablity is not 100.

Comment: so what actually is working behind the scenes??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sim` is a shortcut of **simulate**, not **similarity**. What you got is the **values of the output nodes** of the network `net`. This two values are **independent scores** of belonging to each class. If you want something that is more "probability like" you have to normalize it, to do so, simply divide this vector by its own sum. So change `[a b]` to `[a/(a+b) b/(a+b)]` which will result in the values that sum up to `1` (as desired).

> > If yes what minimum distance Algo it uses.

Neural networks are not based on any sor tof "minimum distance to a class". It is much more complex object, which is derived from regression models, not simple distance measures (although obviously one can explicitly state the kind of "distance to a class" from the neural network weights, but its equation would be really long, especially for high dimensional data like images).